# Using Protocol Buffer Java Bindings in Matlab

Tags: java, matlab, protocol-buffers

I am trying to use Java protobuf stubs inside Matlab. I generated the Java stub and corresponding jar file in Eclipse. I then take the jar file and add it to the Matlab path. In Matlab I do the following:

```
import raven.aos.*; 
import raven.aos.Messages.*;
image = Image.newBuilder();
```

At this point I get an error message that says:

```
??? Undefined variable "Image" or class "Image.newBuilder".
Error in ==> pub>pub.pub at 16
image = Image.newBuilder();
```

I have successfully been able to use the Java jar in a Java project using the exact same syntax. So this validates that my stub is correct. I have also successfully imported and used a different Java library, zmq.jar, in my Matlab project, so to a certain extent this verifies that I know how to import jar files properly into Matlab.

I've refrained from attaching the generated Java stub file since it is very long. I hope that someone can point out what I'm doing wrong with just the code that I've provided. If required, I will add the stub source.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: does `inmem` show the `Image` class is loaded?

Comment: So right after the import I ran disp(inmem) and I got the following: 
'workspacefunc'
'pub'.
Pub is the variable name I gave to my class. So it is not loading it which makes sense considering the original error message. My problem is that I don't know why it's not loading it.

Comment: See [this link](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f4863.html), the section **Making Classes in a JAR File Available**; looks like you have to specify the full filename of the jar.

Comment: The jar file, in my case proto.jar, has been added to the Matlab classpath.txt file. I even tried importing by 'import proto.raven.aos.Messages.*' and that still gives me the same error. I think the path is correct because I can create an instance of Messages when I change the Messages construtor from private to public.
The problem is that Matlab cannot find the Image class which is a nested class inside Messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because generated protocol buffer message classes are inner classes, you need to use Matlab's javaMethod command to get to the static methods. Import statement will not work. Using your example:

```
image = javaMethod('newBuilder','raven.aos.Messages$Image');
```

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/javamethod.html